# SyntaxHighlighter only adding line numbers

Tags: javascript, syntax-highlighting

I can't seem to figure out my problem with [SyntaxHighlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter); It is only adding line numbers, not highlighting the text. I've been able to get the example page to work, but I can't figure out what's going wrong on my own page. I've looked at the page with firebug and ensured that all files are being loaded. The SyntaxHighlighter.all() function is firing, it just isn't doing the only thing I care about... highlighting.

Here is [a link to my development server](http://174.60.55.174/note/penn_state_xss) with the offending code. Only one of the code snippets (the first on the page) should be highlighted, and but it is only adding line numbers.

Thank you very much for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You included the CSS files incorrectly as scripts, and not as "link" tags:

Bad:

```
    <script type='text/css' src='/syntaxhighlighter/styles/shCore.css'></script>
    <script type='text/css' src='/syntaxhighlighter/styles/shCoreMidnight.css'></script>
```

Good:

```
  <link href='/syntaxhighlighter/styles/shCore.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
  <link href='/syntaxhighlighter/styles/shCoreMidnight.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
```

Comment: thank you... every time I post to stack, it seems like i've been caught on the dumbest errors. non the less, you've been a life saver, thank you.

Comment: Not a problem! Glad I could help. Could you do me a solid and mark my answer as an answer by clicking on the check box under the voting block?

Comment: done! i was actually just waiting for stack to let me, theres a countdown before you can accept...  they don't expect such quickly answered questions ha. thanks again!